# Request Header Setup in Swagger Integration With Spring Data Rest

Tags: swagger, spring-data-rest, springfox

I have a Swagger intgration setup for end points generated by Spring Data Rest in a Spring Boot project. The followings are related dependencies I have in the project:

```
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.6.1"
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.6.1"
compile "io.springfox:springfox-data-rest:2.6.1"
compile "io.springfox:springfox-bean-validators:2.6.1"
```

The header setup in Swagger for those end points are varied. For example, I have

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/x-spring-data-compact+json' 'http://localhost:8080/accounts'
```

where the accept or content type in the header should be application/json. How to have the right header setting?

Comment: Isn't there a dropdown box where you can select `application/json` or `application/x-spring-data-compact+json`?

Comment: Yes, there is a dropdown list. But the application/json or application/<>+json isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Swagger about the content types that can be returned by the endpoint by using the @ApiOperation Swagger annotation. For example;

`@ApiOperation(produces = "application/json,application/x-spring-data-compact+json")`

Full example:

```
@RestController
class ExampleController
{
    @ApiOperation(produces = "application/json,application/x-spring-data-compact+json")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/byId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ExampleResponse getById(@RequestParam String id)
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

By doing this they will then appear in the dropdown.